# Nondescript Google Function Error relating to connection conflict during bulk loading with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, database-connection, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for how to properly configure my Google Cloud Functions and/or my Python code they run. I get the following error: "An unknown error has occurred in Cloud Functions"

I manually commented out my code line-by-line and found this can happen if a connection is not properly closed to snowflake. I have to manually delete and recreate the snowflake table each time a google function doesn't properly exit and close the connection.

If a connection isn't terminated properly, I can manually recreate the tables in the db and get this code to run successfully every time as long as nothing else goes wrong e.g. connects to INVOICES_TEMP_PROD. So I've made a INVOICES_TEMP_STG for testing so this is less likely to happen.

```
table='Invoices'
sql = f'DELETE FROM {str.upper(table)}_TEMP_PROD'
con.execute(sql)

con.close()
```

But even still I can't make it past the following code segment without getting the same error. That is, when I'm not executing a single sql command to Snowflake and instead iteratively sending data to the db, it will throw the same connection error.

I can do this code just fine iteratively in Collab. Is there some reason I need to open and close a connection every time I send data to the db in Google Functions that differs from Collab or is there something else I'm doing wrong in this approach? Is there some standard to follow in this env I'm not following? Sample code appreciated.

```
i=0
df = pd.DataFrame()
result = pd.DataFrame()
while((i==0) or (len(df)==top)):
   url2 = 'https://<<<url>>>/v2/<<<Table>>>?$orderby=APICreateDate&$filter=APIRemovedDate eq null&$skip=<<<Skip>>>&$top=<<<Top>>>'
   url_mod = url2.replace('<<<Table>>>',table).replace('<<<Skip>>>',str(i)).replace('<<<Top>>>',str(top))
   r = requests.get(url_mod,auth=(user,passw),headers=headers)
   t = [i for i in r.json().values()]
   df = pd.json_normalize(t[1])
   result = result.append(df,ignore_index=True)
   df_to_sf = result.drop(['odata.etag'],axis=1)
   df_to_sf.columns = df_to_sf.columns.str.upper()
   df_to_sf.to_sql(name=f'{str.lower(table)}_temp_prod',con=con, if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=16384)
   result = pd.DataFrame()
   i += top

con.close()
```

P.S. Before it crashed with that nondescript "unknown error", it does upload some (but not all) data like I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us enough information to reproduce the problem - for example, you never show how the connection `con` is stablished, nor the necessary imports.

As a general Python convention you can use the `with` statement to make sure the connection will be closed at the end of a block:

```py
with snowflake.connector.connect(...) as con:
  code
  code
  code
```

If this is not enough to run the iteration in Cloud Functions, please add more logging, version information, and include the relevant logs in the question:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python#view_logs